# JAVA: JUNIT testing of class type with string

Tags: java, string, class, object, junit

So I have a test which is to test the addNewCustomer method which does so by reading in from a text file

```
@Test
public void testAddNewCustomer() {

    System.out.println("addNewCustomer");
    try {
        File nFile = new File("ProductData.txt");
        File file = new File("CustomerData.txt");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
        ElectronicsEquipmentSupplier ees = new ElectronicsEquipmentSupplier(1, 1, InputFileData.readProductDataFile(nFile));
        ees.addNewCustomer(InputFileData.readCustomerData(scan));
        CustomerDetailsList expResult = ees.getDetails();
        CustomerDetailsList result = ees.getDetails();
        assertEquals(expResult, result);
    } catch (IllegalCustomerIDException | IOException | IllegalProductCodeException e) {
        fail(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The problem that I'm having is to what to have as the expected result? I tried putting a string with the values that I thought would be entered but it then said I can't compare type string with type CustomerDetailsList. Any ideas?

public class CustomerDetailsList {

```
private final ArrayList<CustomerDetails> customerCollection;

public CustomerDetailsList() {
    customerCollection = new ArrayList<>();
}

public void addCustomer(CustomerDetails newCustomer) {
    customerCollection.add(newCustomer);
}

public int numberOfCustomers() {
    return customerCollection.size();
}

public void clearArray() {
    this.customerCollection.clear();
}
/**
 *
 * @param givenID the ID of a customer
 * @return the customer’s details if found, exception thrown otherwise.
 * @throws supplierproject.CustomerNotFoundException
 */
public CustomerDetails findCustomer(String givenID) throws CustomerNotFoundException {
    CustomerNotFoundException notFoundMessage
            = new CustomerNotFoundException("Customer was not found");
    int size = customerCollection.size();
    int i = 0;
    boolean customerFound = false;
    while (!customerFound && i < size) {        
        customerFound = customerCollection.get(i).getCustomerID().equals(givenID);
        i++;
    }
    if (customerFound) {
        return customerCollection.get(i - 1);
    } else {
        throw notFoundMessage;
    }
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder customerDets = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCustomers(); i++) {
        customerDets.append(customerCollection.get(i).toString()).append("\n");

    }
    return customerDets.toString();
}
```

}
The list itself

Comment: This unit-test is wrong on many levels. However in order to stick to your question: where are you comparing a string with a list?

Comment: How is it wrong on many levels? What should I be doing?

Comment: To be honest I would suggest you buy a good book on unit-testing. But just to sum up some things: you're doing integration testing, your assertion in there makes no sense, result-assertions should be predefined and I have some doubts about that try-catch.

Comment: Is there any output from addNewCustomer?

Comment: "your assertion makes no sense" that is the idea of this entire question. Tell me what I'm doing wrong instead of saying buy a good book..

Comment: There is no output, it just adds it to the array

Comment: I asked you where you are comparing a string with a list, which is what your question mentions. I can't help you if you don't help me.

Comment: It is what would be in the test. The string would be the expected and list would be the actual?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, you should test if the new customer is in the list. However, the expResult and result from your test are just the same, because at that point the ees already contains the new customer. Therefore the assertion does not make sense.

However, you can test if the Customer List contains the customer with given email (or some unique property of that customer).

Comment: Okay so how would I test this?

Comment: if your customer list is a collection of some sort, go through und see if the newly inserted customer is there. Can you post the code of CustomerDetailsList?

Comment: do you know the id of the inserted customer? if yes, then you just assertTrue(result.findCustomer(<the_id_of_the_added_customer>) != null);

Comment: Please absolutely do not do assertTrue(..) as shown above.  When the test fails you will get the most useless diagnostics possible

Comment: You are right, MrWiggles.. I usually use assertThat(), but wanted to show the easiest solution

Comment: how would I use AsserThat()??

Comment: Thank you zlobi wan kenobi, nice to see someone actually trying to help me on here rather than being patronising.